# MySQL cursor avg() fetch null

Tags: mysql

I have a computed column in cursor select query.

```sql
drop procedure if exists update_avg;
delimiter $$
create procedure update_avg()
BEGIN
    declare score decimal(9,4);
    declare id varchar(5);
    declare done bool default false;
    declare c_update cursor for
    select stu_id, avg(score) from chooses group by stu_id;
    declare continue HANDLER for not found set done = true; 
    open c_update;
    fetch c_update into id, score;
    select id, score; -- test purpose
    while(not done) do
        update student set average_score = score where student_id = id;
        fetch c_update into id, score;
    end while;
    close c_update;
END
delimiter ;

call update_avg();
```

When I execute this query it works fine:

```sql
select stu_id, avg(score) from chooses group by stu_id;
```

```
|stu_id|avg(score)|
|------|----------|
|1     |   73.5000|
|10    |   93.0000|
|11    |   53.0000|
...
```

And when I `call update_avg();` output:

```
|id|score|
|--|-----|
|1 |NULL |
```

My question is why this cursor cannot fetch `avg(score)` from select query and how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This operation does not require cursor and could be done using correlated subquery:

```
update student 
set average_score = (SELECT AVG(score) 
                     FROM chooses 
                     WHERE chooses.stu_id = student.student_id)
-- WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM chooses WHERE chooses.stu_id = student.student_id)
-- this condition is to avoid updating rows 
-- that do not have corresponding rows in chooses table
```

Comment: Thanks! That works. But I still wonder why cursor cannot fetch avg().